# EditText: Can't type in content, when the EditText has focus sometimes

Tags: android, android-edittext

Sometimes, I can't type in any content to the `EditText`, even if the `EditText` has focus.

But, I can input content through `adb shell input keyevent 34`, then character 'f' will be displayed on the `EditText`.

I have no idea why the `EditText` can't input text, even if it has focus.

I can reproduce this problem on several android devices.

Comment: when you select EditText, does the soft keyboard shows up or not?

Comment: when I select the EditText, the soft keyboard will show up, I can tap the keys on the soft keyboard, but the EditText can't receive the input characters.

Comment: I have never faced such issue, but I guess many other have faced it see this two posts : 1)https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/kXB6i5ecIF4 
          2)http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=1&q=17508&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&id=17508

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code it is hard to tell. Do you use an OnKeyPress listener in your activity? You could be catching the key presses and throwing them away.